# How to check for code sourcecode (parent) for python in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm beginning to use vscode for python development. I'm a novice programmer in general, so I'm not sure what is the standard way of describing what I want:
is a way , that things like pycharms provide, to check the source code of say, a class or a function, with one keyboard shortcut.

I've tried installing the Class IO extension, but doesn't seem to work..
I've tried the below keyboard shortcut specificationo in keybindings.json.

```
[{
"key": "shift+alt+g",
"command": "classio.goToParent",
"when": "editorLangId == 'python'"
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you want is the "[Go to definition](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-definition)" functionality

> If a language supports it, you can go to the definition of a symbol by
>   pressing F12.
>
> If you press Ctrl and hover over a symbol, a preview of the
>   declaration will appear
>
> Tip: You can jump to the definition with Ctrl+Click or open the
>   definition to the side with Ctrl+Alt+Click.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can consult the VS Code Keyboard Shortcuts (Windows) sheet at:

https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf

If you want to check the class definition (where you declared the class) your shortcut is `F12`. I hope this sheet can be useful enough for you to get started in VS Code.

Linux: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf

MacOS: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf